# Artifactory - virtual repositories

Tags: artifactory

I am planning to set up an artifactory vitual repo and it includes all the public repos and 3 local repos. 4 local repos are based on 3 teams say A, B, C. I want team A to resolve artifacts from only local repo A, team B to resolve artifacts from only repo B and so on. 
How can I do this?

Note: In order to save the pain of maintaining who has access to which repo ( team members constantly move between teams), i have given access to all repos to all team members. I do not want to restrict them to their own repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the isolation of a certain repository per team is required, some maintenance will always be needed and there's not much way around it.

Probably the simplest way to achieve this is to create permission targets per team (instead of per developer) and associate each target with a group designated for that team; When a developer is relocated remove him from the group of one team and add him to the group of another.

If you trust your developers, you can also create a resolver profile per team that'll point to the team's repository; when a developer is relocated he can simply switch to use a different profile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I can't create permission based on team cos I am using artifactory Open source. Can you suggest another solution please?

Comment: I meant I cannot use LDAP groups in Artifactory Open source. I need to manually create my own groups. So i need another alernative

Comment: Then why not maintain the groups within Artifactory?

Comment: Also, you should add these details to your question.

Comment: Maintaining people in artifactory groups means I have to do my work twice... maintaining people in LDAP groups as well as Artifactory groups.Just a teeny weeny bit of pain. But I will take Artifactory groups as the solution for now. I tried it and it works. THanks!